# Call react component with string not by its name

Tags: reactjs, string, function, methods, react-props

How can i call the react function component with string
Ex i have function component name function1
 `<function1   {...props} />`
What if  **i have** string name and want call it linke function component
 `<name  {...props />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be doing something in the likes of :

```js
import React from "react";
import UserA from "./userA";
import UserB from "./userB";

const components = {
  usera: UserA,
  userb: UserB
};

function DynamicComponent(props) {
  const SelectUser = components[props.user];
  return <SelectUser />;
}

export default DynamicComponent;
```

Comment: tks you so much